# Options for building a ramp on a steep hill

Tags: landscaping

I have ten acres and all of it is hillside. When you get to the top of the hill, it's wonderful! It flattens out, it's beautiful and I love spending time up there.  My house sits at the bottom of the hill and the problem I have is that the bottom of the hill is very steep due to hillside erosion. I would guess standing at ground level that the really steep part goes up in height to about six feet.

I have been researching options on how to put together a ramp of some kind (for an ATV) and there seem to be a few options. I can't have one part of the hillside to become structurally unsound (by moving dirt from it) at the expense of a trying to create a decent slope.

Obviously I would love to find a cost effective way to put some sort of ramp and maybe there are options I just don't know about. I haven't priced out the cost of having someone to move bring in rocks and dirt for this.

Are there any ramp experts/excavators who could chime in on this or at least point me to some resources?

J

Comment: Terracing with stone and or stabilizing with shrubs. More later when I have a keyboard

Answer (score 3):

With ten acres you need a landscape plan to fit your needs. Whether you do it yourself or hire a professional the time/money you spend now will reward you in the years to come as the landscape grows into place.

A site with slope is a huge advantage in creating a truly unique and wonderful experience but you need to know what you want. You could incorporate some of the principles of [permaculture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permaculture) in your design to minimize energy inputs and maximize productivity. As an example grape vines grow well on slopes if they face the sun.  For more every day solutions to slopes check these excellent answers here

- [control erosion on a steep trail](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/2380/how-can-i-control-erosion-on-a-steep-trail)
- [control weeds on a retaining wall](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/5755/how-can-i-control-erosion-and-weeds-on-a-rock-retaining-wall)
- [ground covers for slopes](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4589/ground-cover-for-large-sloped-area/4592#4592)

For a how to on building steps and ramps I will shamelessly refer to my answer [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4340/building-natural-stone-steps/4341#4341) which gives you an idea of the labour involved for ramps. Not easy but classic.

Comment: I will look over this now and I appreciate your input, especially the stabilizing with shrubs!